# how to check an empty field using Enable Rules in visual ribbon editor

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to change my button Enable rules according to value rule using visual ribbon editor.
The rule is - if the field is empty the button will be disabled, I insert my data to visual ribbon editor like this :

```
Enable Rules - 
field: myFieldName
value:""   //I tried Null instead of "", it didn't work
default:false
Invert result:true
```

the output now is: buttons act the same if the field is empty or not...
Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

It should would with `null` instead of `Null`

https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/121427-enable-disable-a-ribbon-button-dynamically-based-o